# Azure Devops - Get IdentityRef of user by username

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on an extension to azure devops. The intent is to create pull requests automatically when changes are pushed to a specific branch and then add some reviewers to it.

There is `GitPullRequest` in the [azure devops node api](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/tree/master/api) and it is possible to add reviewers to it by doing:

```
const pr: gi.GitPullRequest = <gi.GitPullRequest>{};

// ... some lines omitted...

pr.reviewers = [];
const reviewer = <gi.IdentityRefWithVote> {id: tl.getVariable("Build.RequestedForId")}
pr.reviewers.push(reviewer);
```

The above adds a reviewer to the PR (by taking the id from the environment variable). I would like to also use the username of team members eg. `me@example.com` look up their id and add those to the reviewers. I've tried using the usernames as `uniqueName` for the `IdentityRefWithVote` and adding those, but it complains that the identifier is missing.

Is there a way of doing this? The only way I have come up with is to fetch all the teams and then for each team fetch the members and then match up the identities that way. However, that seems convoluted :(